# Adding buttons to wp-admin/edit-comments

Tags: comments

I want to add my own buttons to the comments editor table:

[image]

I tried to understand what happens in wp-admin/comment.php , edit-comments.php, includes/class-wp-comments-table-lists.php etc. but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two filters for that:

- **manage_edit-comments_columns** - to add a column header on comments table
- **manage_comments_custom_column** - to add the content of each row for that column

So you would have something like this:

```
function myplugin_comment_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns['my_custom_column'] = __( 'My Category' );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', 'myplugin_comment_columns' );

function myplugin_comment_column( $column, $comment_ID )
{
    if ( 'my_custom_column' == $column ) {
        echo '<a href="' . admin_url('/my-action.php?id=' . $comment_ID) . '">My button</a>';
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_comments_custom_column', 'myplugin_comment_column', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ! But where do I put it? :)

Comment: You can put it on functions.php of your theme or create a plugin with this. If you're just using a 3rd party theme and don't want to create a plugin, you can always create a child theme from your current theme and put this code inside that functions.php.

Comment: What do you have on your side?