# Add functionality to block comment authors in the Comment edit pag

Tags: functions, comments, comment-meta

[image]

I want to add an additional button to the Comments edit admin page, allowing me to ban the ips or emails in one click. After clicking the button, it should probably lead me to the Comment Moderation section and add IP or email to the list. Or maybe it's bad solution and smb knows better way

I didn't find any plugin for my needs. There is only one ticket which can help me to add my own button,([Adding buttons to wp-admin/edit-comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271671/adding-buttons-to-wp-admin-edit-comments)) but I'm not sure how to connect it to the Comment Moderation section

Any ideas on how to write the proper function?

[image]